# Not able to have commands in User-Defined functions in Kusto

Tags: azure-data-explorer

I am trying to create a function that will accept name of tag and a datetime value and drop a extent within a specific table which has that tag and then ingest a new record into that table with the same tag and the input datetime value -- sort of 'update' simulation. I am not bothered about performance, it's just going to hold metadata -- maybe 20-30 rows at max.

So this is how the create table looks:-

```
.create table MyTable(sometext:string,somevalue:datetime)
```

And shown below is my function creation step, which is failing:-

```
.create-or-alter function MyFunction(arg_sometext:string,arg_somedate:datetime) 
{
.drop extents <| .show table MyTable extents where tags has arg_sometext;
.ingest inline into table MyTable with (tags="[arg_sometext]") <| arg_somedate
}
```

So you can see I am trying to do something simple -- I am suspecting that Kusto won't allow commands in a function. Is there any workaround for achieving this?

Answer (score 4):

**Generally:**
Kusto mandates that control commands start with a dot (`.`), and that this must be the first character in the text of the command. As queries, functions, etc. don't start with a dot, this precludes them from invoking control commands.

This is an intentional limitation that prevents a wide range of code injection attacks. By imposing this rule, Kusto makes it easy to guarantee that any query that does not begin with a dot will only have read access to the data and metadata, and never be able to alter them.

**Specifically:** with regards to your specific scenario:

- I'm assuming it's triggered automatically (even if you did have the option to create a function), which suggests you should be able to achieve your goal using Kusto's API / Client libraries and a simple script/app.
- An alternative, and perhaps even better approach, would be to re-consider if you actually need to delete or update specific records, or you can use `summarize arg_max()` in order to query for only the latest "versions" of the records (you could also create a function which encapsulates that logic and overrides the table, by naming the function with the table's name).