# Kusto using ingest in function throws recognition error

Tags: azure, azure-data-explorer, kql

I am trying to use ingest code inside a kusto function to insert record into a kusto table. I see the below error while running the query. Is there option to use ingest inside a kusto function?

```
.create function with (docstring = "test ingest") Insertbackups {
.ingest inline into table backup <| 
"test", 2, "Succeeded", 1, 2, 1.1, 3, false 
}
```

Error: A recognition error occurred. Token: .

Answer (score 2):

That isn't supported. You can find the full explanation in the following post: [Not able to have commands in User-Defined functions in Kusto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55387392/not-able-to-have-commands-in-user-defined-functions-in-kusto)