# KQL Kusto: Result of table management command as an input

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql, kusto-explorer

I am going to create a policy update by takeing policy defintion from another table.
Let's assume, we have a *sampleTable* table with the following definition:

```
.alter table sampleTable policy update @'[{"Source": "sourceTable", "Query": "function()", "IsEnabled": "True", "IsTransactional": false}]';
```

I would like to use policy for a newTable which were used for sampleTable. I have tried to do something like below:

```
let definition = (.show table sampleTable policy update | project Policy);
.alter table sampleTable policy update definition ;
```

I deeply belive, that it is doable, but I don't know the syntax here.

Could you please support me?

Comment: If the answer below answers your question, please accept it by clicking the "V" icon. If you're still missing info, please add a comment elaborating what info you need. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. a control command must start with a dot (`.`): https://stackoverflow.com/a/55387571/7861807
2. you need to explicitly specify the policy as a string literal. you can't base it on a result of a different query/command.
3. you can orchestrate this programmatically using the API - run a command to get the policy definition (as a string), then generate the following command using that string, then invoke the generated command.