# Unable to use .set-or-replace inside a .create function in Kusto

Tags: azure-data-explorer

```
.create-or-alter function with (folder = "Validation") SaveValidate() 
{
   .set-or-replace ValidationResults with (tags='["new"]') <|
   Validate
}
```

A recognition error occurred.
Token: .

Line: 2, Position: 0

clientRequestId: KustoWebV2;ccc2de76-4cb5-481a-a593-1857215fd8fb

Comment: please see the following post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55387571/7861807

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Not able to have commands in User-Defined functions in Kusto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55387392/not-able-to-have-commands-in-user-defined-functions-in-kusto)