# Kusto Function to load

Tags: azure-data-explorer

I want to create a function in Kusto that appends data into a table from another function
This is what I want to run  .append SamTable<|extract_elements_from_internal()

So when I create another function called 'etl' it fails

```
.create-or-alter function with (docstring = "Convert avro_ingest to avro_destination",folder = "ingestxxx") etl() {
         .append SamTable<|extract_elements_from_internal()  // this appends to the SamTable from the function and runs outside without issues
    }
```

Any ideas?

I've went through all the documentation and didn't find anything on this. ChatGPT suggested this below but that fails too

`.create function AppendToSamTable() { SamTable <| extract_elements_from_internal() }`

Answer (score 0):

Running commands in a store function isn't supported. You can find the full explanation in the following post: [Not able to have commands in User-Defined functions in Kusto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55387392/not-able-to-have-commands-in-user-defined-functions-in-kusto)

Comment: Thanks Yoni. Seems there are many restrictions ...